# Переход к якорям посредством switch case JavaScript /JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать `switch/case` для перехода между якорями посредством нажатия горячих клавиш. По задумке хотелось бы так: при нажатии `ctrlKey + keyCode` (один из) переходило к определенному якорю.

**Вопрос:** как вставить в конструкцию кэйсов еще и контрол?

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // var b = e.keyCode;
    switch (keyCode) {
        case (e.keyCode == 49):
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 49)
                window.location.href = "#sec01"
            break;
        case (e.keyCode == 50):
            window.location.href = "#sec02"
            break;
        case (e.keyCode == 51):
            window.location.href = "#sec03"
            break;
        case (e.keyCode == 52):
            window.location.href = "#sec04"
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если клавиша Ctrl должна быть нажата обязательно, вынесите ее за switch, (то есть switch внутри блока if). Если не обязательно, то внутри отдельных case, где это необходимо.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 49:
                window.location.href= "#sec01";
                break;
            case 50:
                window.location.href= "#sec02";
                break;
            case 51:
                window.location.href= "#sec03";
                break;
            case 52:
                window.location.href= "#sec04"
                break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, однако не работает. Не затруднит ли вас показать как верно это реализовать?

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Премного благодарен! Забыл в начале задать е перед Котролом :)

Comment: Бывает. Внимательнее)

Comment: Тут проще будет использовать массив чем `switch`.